# How to fix 'Missing argument 1 for Pdf_label::__construct()' when using fpdf label script in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

Im getting error :

> Message: Missing argument 1 for Pdf_label::__construct(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project1b\system\core\Loader.php on line 1285 and
>   defined
>
> Filename: libraries/PDF_Label.php

what I'm trying to do is, I tried to using fpdf label script [(Documentation Here)](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php) in codeigniter, I already tried a simple pdf generate in codeigniter using this code :

```
public function cetakLabelfpdf()
    {
        $this->load->library('fpdf');

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!');
        $pdf->Output();
    }
```

and it worked, but when I tried to add script (in this case label script) I put the label script in the same directory like fpdf file does (application/libraries) and generate pdf using this example code

```
public function cetakLabelfpdf()
{
    $this->load->library('PDF_Label');

    // Standard format
    $pdf = new PDF_Label('L7163');

    $pdf->AddPage();

    // Print labels
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
        $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s %s, %s", "Laurent $i", 'Immeuble Toto', 'av. Fragonard', '06000', 'NICE', 'FRANCE');
        $pdf->Add_Label($text);
    }

    $pdf->Output();
}
```

I'm getting like on the first message, I really appreciate it if someone can show what I did wrong on this case.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a ci library, and there exists many repos for fpdf, which are you using? if you aren't using any codeigniter libraries to use fpdf, why are you loading it like one? i think that is where your error lies, as when you are loading the label class via `$this->load` it is initializing the label class without the required constructor parameter.

Comment: @Alex I straight download it from http://www.fpdf.org/ , I'll try to find solution for initializing the label with required constructor, thx

Comment: afaik fpdf.org doesn't have a codeigniter lib. you should not attempt to load it at all via `$this->load->library()` and instead, use a require on the top of the classes that need it. the just initialize it like any other php class (like you are doing with the new word). let me know what happens...

Comment: @Alex thanks a lot sir, I try your suggestion to replace $this->load->library() to required() and the code works !!

if you can explain the difference in $this->load->library() and require() in this codeigniter case I'll really appreciate it.

NB : please answer it in answer button so I can mark is as the answer.

Comment: sure thing. glad i could help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to my comment, essentially `$this->load` is meant to work with CodeIgniter compatible libraries/models/helpers .etc. When you have something completely unrelated to CodeIgniter (not built around its ecosystem) you can either create a library to "adapt" the class to be compatible with CodeIgniter or you can just use it like a regular class with either composer autoloading or requiring the necessary files at the top of the controller/model class that needs it (won't work for namespaced classes - you'd then need composer or something that can *autoload*).

In your specific case, when you called `$this->load->library()` on the label class, CI created a `new` label class (behind the scene) and didn't pass anything to its `__construct` where there is a required param. Hence the error. You *can* pass variables to a libraries constructor via `$this->load->library('some_lib', ['arg1'=>'foo', 'arg2'=>'bar']` however that is only if the library is built for CI (receives all constructor arguments in an array rather than a comma separated parameter list).

See more here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#passing-parameters-when-initializing-your-class

Comment: it really good to have this explanation so I can learn more about CI, thanks a lot.